# Multiple putextra Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: java, android

I want to pass a custom object between my activities. I implemented Parceable for this class and put it in a extra. It works like a charm. Except if I put some other extras. In this case the app crash with this error : Unmarshalling unknown type code.

I have 2 class : A and B. A has a private field B. et my class B has a nested enum Enum. I implemented Parceable for A, B and Enum.

There is my code, I have rewritten it to be more concise.

A.java

```
public class A implements Parcelable {
  B objectB;
  String myString;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(myString);
    out.writeParcelable(objectB, flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Adresse> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Adresse>() {
    public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Adresse(in);
    }

    public A[] newArray(int size) {
        return new A[size];
    }
};

private Adresse(Parcel in) {
    myString = in.readString();
    objectB = in.readParcelable(B.class.getClassLoader());
}
}
```

B.java

```
public class B implements Parceable {
   Bitmap bitmap;
   String otherString;
   Enum enum;

   public enum Enum implements Parceable {
     ONE ("One")
     TWO ("Two")

     @Override
       public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
       }

     @Override
       public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(ONE.name);
        out.writeString(TWO.name);
      }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<Identifiant> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Enum>() {
        public Enum createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return Enum.values()[in.readInt()];
        }

        public Enum[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Enum[size];
        }
    };
   }

  public B(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
  }

  @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

    out.writeString(otherString);
    out.writeParcelable(bitmap, flags);
    out.writeParcelable(enum, flags);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    otherString = in.readString();
    bitmap = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
    enum =  in.readParcelable(Enum.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {

    public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new B(in);
    }

    public B[] newArray(int size) {
        return new B[size];
    }

};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  A objectA = new A();
  bundle.putParcelable("A", a);
  bundle.putInt("Int", 1);  //If I comment this line it works

  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```